# Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, corda, gradle-plugin

I am unable to run my corda project under corporate environment/desktop. I have been building this project on my personal desktop but right now I am going to shift it to my work desktop and is unable to build the project by applying script build.gradle. I have research on this but still have 0 clues about what might be the caused.

My build.gradle file:

```
        buildscript {
    ext.corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
    ext.corda_release_version = '3.3-corda'
    ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.2.1'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    ext.junit_version = '4.12'
    ext.quasar_version = '0.7.9'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordapp:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordformation:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-dev/' }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "config/dev"
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "config/test"
        }
    }
    integrationTest {
        kotlin {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integrationTest/kotlin')
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    // Corda integration dependencies
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"

    testCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"

    // CorDapp dependencies
    // Specify your CorDapp's dependencies below, including dependent CorDapps.
    // We've defined Cash as a dependent CorDapp as an example.
    cordapp project(":cordapp")
    cordapp project(":cordapp-contracts-states")
    cordapp project(":oracle")
    cordapp project(":banking")
    cordapp "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"

    testCompile project(path: ':cordapp', configuration: 'testOutput')
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: []) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        languageVersion = "1.1"
        apiVersion = "1.1"
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        javaParameters = true   // Useful for reflection.
    }
}

task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating: false]
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10003")
            adminAddress("localhost:10043")
        }
        cordapps = []
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:banking:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version",
                "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
        ]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10009")
            adminAddress("localhost:10049")
        }
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:banking:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version",
                "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
        ]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=Oracle,L=New York,C=US"
        p2pPort 10011
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10012")
            adminAddress("localhost:10052")
        }

        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:banking:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:oracle:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version",
                "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
        ]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
}

task runTemplateClient(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.template.ClientKt'
    args 'localhost:10006'
}
```

and the error:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:882)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1500(DefaultConfiguration.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:856)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:382)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.getScriptClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:73)
Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51.
Required by:
    project :
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ComponentState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:854)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ComponentState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:865)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$EdgeState.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:446)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$EdgeState.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:417)
Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51 available for offline mode.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.StartParameterResolutionOverride$FailedRemoteAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(StartParameterResolutionOverride.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:116)
    Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:3.2.1.
Required by:
    project :
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ComponentState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:854)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ComponentState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:865)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$EdgeState.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:446)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$EdgeState.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:417)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.attachToTargetRevisionsSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:223)
Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of net.corda.plugins:cordapp:3.2.1 available for offline mode.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.StartParameterResolutionOverride$FailedRemoteAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(StartParameterResolutionOverride.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:66)
    Cause 3: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:3.2.1.
Required by:
    project :
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ComponentState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:854)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ComponentState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:865)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$EdgeState.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:446)
.....
```

Comment: that might be an issue with the corda artifactory, I'll confirm if this is the case.

Comment: The plugins come from maven (`mavenCentral` in your build.gradle).

Is it possible that your corporate environment is preventing you from downloading from these repositories?

Answer (score 2):

According to the error log you posted, I believe your Gradle is configured to work in "offline mode", so it doesn't try to download dependencies if you don't already have them cached locally.

You can disable it in different ways depending on the way you're using Gradle:

- if it's called from the command line then remove `--offline`;
- if you're using it via IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio then toggle the following button (from the Gradle tool window on the right-hand side of the IDE):

  [image: Gradle offline mode button]
- if you're using Eclipse, then you'll find a checkbox called "offline mode" under Gradle preferences
- Other IDEs will have a similar setting as well